# How to have "Preserve Layer and Table IDs" option enabled by default

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, map-service, publishing

A ability to [preserve layer and table IDs](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/map-authoring-considerations.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_4C54586DEB0445B4B97AF15856E546AB) between map service updates is a great feature added at 10.3.1. Unfortunatly it seems that it has to be manually applied to each dataframe when an .mxd is created.

Is there a way to have it enabled by default? Map publishers rarely remember to enable it and I occasionally end up having to edit my applications after updates anyway.

***Edit***
Found a relevant [thread on geonet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/142569), it looks like you can't set this option through ArcObjects but you can set/change layerIDs on individual layers

***Edit 2***
Link to an [idea I submitted](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/12480-ability-to-have-preserve-layer-and-table-ids-option-enabled-by-default) at the ArcGIS ideas web site in case anybody else would find this useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but there is no standard way to have this enabled so it will apply to all map documents one creates. There is no `arcpy` way into the data frame to see whether the layer ids have been enabled and there is no way to check the layer id using `arcpy` either.

If you are comfortable with ArcObjects, you might consider iterating your map documents and enabling this option.

You might also consider submitting an idea on the [ArcGIS Ideas](https://geonet.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas) website.

It is possible to [customize the menu](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/finding-tools/adding-and-removing-tools-on-menus-and-toolbars.htm) adding additional items, just to remind the publishers to activate this option. The customization can be shared between machines, so it can be applied to all the users involved.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Found a thread discussing doing this in ArcObjects, doesn't look like it's possible. I've updated the question. Also I submitted an idea to the ideas website.

Comment: Ah OK, good to know. As a crazy idea to share - I've updated my answer.